# upload a file to alfresco repository example throws error

Tags: file-upload, alfresco

AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.generalException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: 
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://www.alfresco.org/ws/service/repository/1.0}RepositoryFault:0org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.datatype.TypeConversionException: Failed to convert date XYZ to string
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}exceptionName:org.alfresco.repo.webservice.repository.RepositoryFault
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:
    at org.alfresco.repo.webservice.repository.RepositoryWebService.update(RepositoryWebService.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

```
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:PVARANCHI00145


at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer.<init>(BeanDeserializer.java:104)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer.<init>(BeanDeserializer.java:90)
at org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryFault.getDeserializer(RepositoryFault.java:146)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseDeserializerFactory.getSpecialized(BaseDeserializerFactory.java:154)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseDeserializerFactory.getDeserializerAs(BaseDeserializerFactory.java:84)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.getDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:464)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.getDeserializerForType(DeserializationContext.java:547)
at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultDetailsBuilder.onStartChild(SOAPFaultDetailsBuilder.java:157)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
at org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.update(RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.java:986)
at UploadFileAction.upload(UploadFileAction.java:152)
at UploadFileAction.main(UploadFileAction.java:54)
```

Error uploading file :

am i missing something?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a problem with the date conversion - somehow your SOAP client is not compatible, unfortunately I can't really help you with that.

I would suggest not using the SOAP API directly and switch to the CMIS API by using the [OpenCMIS Java client](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html) on the client side. It is well tested and will save you a lot of headaches as long as your requirements are all covered by the CMIS spec (CRUD, search).